# Bootstrap Popover viewport property

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, viewport, popover

I'm trying the bootstrap's popover but I can not use it inside a container with

```
overflow: hidden;
```

To avoid this problem I tried to set the viewport property to "body", but this doesn't work because the popover is built in the same place of the target.

I also tried to update bootstrap to v3.3.4 but seems that viewport property is fully ignored!

Comment: No... and this was the answer! Thank you. It works, if you want to answer me I will accept your answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[From bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers), tooptip options:

Viewport: Keeps the popover within the bounds of this element.

Container: Appends the popover to a specific element.

You are looking for container not viewport option.    `container:'body'`